# How do I properly import functions from a C++ DLL into my C# Project

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling, dllimport

I could use help with how to properly import several functions from a C++ DLL into my C# application.  Here are a couple examples from the C++ side that show what I am trying to do in C#.  I do not think I am properly marshaling either/or some of the return types and some of the parameters (especially pointers/ref/out).

C++ Header File Declarations:

```
unsigned long __stdcall mfcsez_initialisation(unsigned short serial);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_get_serial(unsigned long int handle,
                                        unsigned short * serial);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_read_chan(unsigned long int handle,
                                       unsigned char canal,
                                       float * pressure,
                                       unsigned short * chrono);
```

C++ Code:

```
/* Define functions prototype */
typedef unsigned long(__stdcall *init)(int);

typedef unsigned char(__stdcall *serial)(unsigned long handle, unsigned 
                                         short *serial);

typedef unsigned char(__stdcall *readChannel)(unsigned long handle, 
                                              unsigned char chan, 
                                              float * pressure, 
                                              unsigned short * chrono);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     unsigned char pressureChannel = 1; 
     HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL=NULL;

     /* Load DLL into memory */
     hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("mfcs64_c.dll"));

     /* Declare pointers on dll functions */
     init dll_init;
     serial dll_serial;
     readChannel dll_readChannel;

     /* Link dll pointers with functions prototype */
     dll_init = (init)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, 
                                     "mfcsez_initialisation");
     dll_serial = (serial)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, 
                                         "mfcs_get_serial");
     dll_readChannel = (readChannel)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, 
                                                   "mfcs_read_chan");

     /* Define variables used for MFCS device */
     unsigned long mfcsHandle;
     unsigned short mySerial;
     float read_pressure;
     unsigned short chrono;
     int loop_index;


     if (hGetProcIDDLL != NULL) 
     {        
         std::cout << "mfcs_c.dll is loaded" << std::endl;

         /* Initialize device */
         if (dll_init != NULL) 
         {         
             /* Initialize the first MFCS in Windows enumeration list */
             mfcsHandle = dll_init(0);
         }

          /* Read device serial number */
          dll_serial(mfcsHandle, &mySerial);

          for (loop_index = int(start_pressure); 
               loop_index<target_pressure; loop_index++)
          {
               Sleep(1000);                                                                      
               dll_readChannel(mfcsHandle, pressureChannel, 
                               &read_pressure, &chrono);
          }
     }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have tried importing them with various footprints.  I am able to call mfcsez_initialisation and it works just fine as imported below.  The other two I have tried many different ways and always get an exception - either from the DLL (unrecoverable) or from improper marshalling which I can try/catch.

Example of C# Import Statements:

```
    [DllImport("mfcs_c_64.dll", CallingConvention = 
               CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    protected static unsafe extern uint mfcsez_initialisation(ushort                         
                                                        serial_number);

    [DllImport("mfcs_c_64.dll", CallingConvention = 
               CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static unsafe extern byte mfcs_get_serial(uint handle, ref 
                                                     ushort serial);

    [DllImport("mfcs_c_64.dll", CallingConvention = 
               CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    protected static unsafe extern byte mfcs_read_chan(ulong handle, byte 
                          canal, ref float pressure, ref ushort chrono);
```

Example of C# Code:

```
unit mfcsHandle = mfcsez_initialisation(0);  // Returns with valid handle

mfcs_get_serial(mfcsHandle, mySerial);  // Memory write exception

float pressure = -1.0f;
ushort chrono = 0;
mfcs_read_chan(mfcsHandle, 1, ref pressure, ref chrono);  // Same ex
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: bible fro this is adam nathans book. https://www.amazon.com/NET-COM-Complete-Interoperability-Guide/dp/067232170X

Comment: @pm100 Er, that book is for COM, there is no COM here at all

Comment: Looking again at the question I see this `mfcs_get_serial(mfcsHandle, mySerial);` That code does not compile. The second argument is a `ref` parameter. I know you'll say, that was just a typo, but if we aren't looking at the same code as you, isn't that a waste of time for everybody.

Comment: I strongly recommend against using the C# type alias keywords in p/invoke declarations.  You're just too tempted to compare the names to the C++ names.  Look, your type of the first parameter to `mfcs_read_chan` became 64-bits again, but it completely slipped by you.  The *readable* declaration would be: `static extern Byte mfcs_read_chan(UInt32 handle, Byte canal, ref Single pressure, ref UInt16 chrono);`  Now it's obvious that you are thinking in terms of the number of bits, not the "`long`" name of the type.  even better, add `using UInt8 = System.Byte` and write the return type as `UInt8`.

Comment: Ben that's a great tip cause you are right the ulong slipped by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have stated in comments (subsequently deleted), you can't be sure whether the problem lies in the interop or the parameters passed to the function. How are you going to resolve that doubt?

The way to do that is to create a test bed DLL that has functions with the same signatures, and then prove that you can move data correctly between that DLL and your C# p/invoke code. Once you can do that you can remove interop as a potential source of your problem, and concentrate on the parameters passed to the function. So, here is what is needed to make that test bed DLL.

**dllmain.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**Dll1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"

{
    unsigned long __stdcall mfcsez_initialisation(unsigned short serial)
    {
        std::cout << "mfcsez_initialisation, " << serial << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_get_serial(unsigned long int handle,
        unsigned short * serial)
    {
        std::cout << "mfcs_get_serial, " << handle << std::endl;
        *serial = 2;
        return 3;
    }

    unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_read_chan(unsigned long int handle,
        unsigned char canal,
        float * pressure,
        unsigned short * chrono)
    {
        std::cout << "mfcs_read_chan, " << handle << ", " << static_cast<int>(canal) << std::endl;
        *pressure = 4.5f;
        *chrono = 5;
        return 6;
    }

}
```

**Dll1.def**

```
LIBRARY   Dll1
EXPORTS  
   mfcsez_initialisation  
   mfcs_get_serial
   mfcs_read_chan
```

Note that I am using a .def file to ensure that functions are exported using their undecorated names.

The C# program that calls this looks like so:

**Program1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string dllname = "Dll1.dll";

        [DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern uint mfcsez_initialisation(ushort serial);

        [DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern byte mfcs_get_serial(uint handle, out ushort serial);

        [DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern byte mfcs_read_chan(uint handle, byte canal, out float pressure, out ushort chrono);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            uint retval1 = mfcsez_initialisation(11);
            Console.WriteLine("return value = " + retval1.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();

            ushort serial;
            byte retval2 = mfcs_get_serial(12, out serial);
            Console.WriteLine("serial = " + serial.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("return value = " + retval2.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();

            float pressure;
            ushort chrono;
            byte retval3 = mfcs_read_chan(13, 14, out pressure, out chrono);
            Console.WriteLine("pressure = " + pressure.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("chrono = " + chrono.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("return value = " + retval3.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
mfcsez_initialisation, 11
return value = 1

mfcs_get_serial, 12
serial = 2
return value = 3

mfcs_read_chan, 13, 14
pressure = 4.5
chrono = 5
return value = 6
```

As you can see, all the desired values travel between the two modules correctly. This demonstrates that the p/invoke interop code here is correct.

**Notes**:

1. In C++ on windows, both `int` and `long int` are 32 bit types. They therefore map to `int` on C#`, or`uint` for unsigned variants.
2. On C#, `long` and `ulong` are 64 bit types, and so do not match C++ `int` or long int`.
3. Map `unsigned char` on C++ to `byte` on C#.
4. There is no need for unsafe here. You would use `unsafe` if you needed to use pointers, but you don't, and seldom do.
5. I used `out` rather than `ref` because I infer that these parameters are only used for data flowing out of the DLL.

If you use this interop code against your DLL and still encounter failure then there are two plausible explanations:

1. The parameters you are passing to the DLL are incorrect.
2. The DLL is not what you think it is. Perhaps you have a version of the DLL which was built against different header files.

Comment: David - you were right all along.  I want to thank you and tell you that I am eating crow right now.  I was trying to avoid getting back into C++...it's been 25 years since I wrote or managed anything in C++.  Argh.  This morning I dug into C++ and managed to get the example C++ app the vendor gave me working and what I found was I could run and use their 32-bit DLL just fine.  However, when I swapped to their 64-bit DLL I got the same exact explosions.  I'm guessing it's something to do with 64 bit vs 32 bit pointers.  You are a good man.  You have my humble apologies, good sir.

Comment: PS - Thanks for cleaning up the comments as well.  I owe you a beer...or three.

Comment: Apology accepted. The mods deleted the comments, not me. I think my answer at your other question can be accepted as well. As for your 64 bit DLL you will need to contact its developer. Bonne chance.

Comment: The French software team fixed their broken DLL and sent me a new 64 bit DLL this morning.  Everything is working perfectly!  If you can believe it they changed the signature of their handle to an unsigned long long in the C++, So I reverted back to a ulong for the handle in C#.  In other news you’ll be very proud of me as I had another unmanaged DLL from horiba for their spectrometer camera and it was using unsafe in the pinvoke statements when not needed. I reworked their code and proved the safe keyword unneeded and sent the vendor programmers a note to help them fix their SDK.

Comment: Thank you, David!  I’ve learned a ton the last few days and am appreciative!

Comment: Probably the handle type should be `void*` in C++ and `IntPtr` in C#. Changing universally to a 64 bit type will break any exisring 32 bit programs that run against the new dll without recompilation. That breaks the golden rule of DLLs. The developer of this dll sounds somewhat incompetent.

Answer (score -1):

It depends what this DLL is besides written in C++.

If it is a C++ .NET DLL, you can use it like any other .NET DLL. And like the ones you already use provided by the Framework.

If it was written with .NET's predecessor COM in mind, you can use COM interop. Backwards compatibiltiy was thought about when making .NET

If it is neither of those, there is P/Invoke.

Note that COM interop and P/Invoke usually involve handling naked pointers. That means binarity issues and having to go into Unmanaged Code. I do not envy you for having to go that low level language.

Comment: Yeah - it's old school straight up unmanaged code.  :(  I've been pulling my hair out for 3 days now.

Comment: As somebody that originally learned in native C++: Good luck with that.

Comment: Yeah...I was a C/C++ guy from the early nineties but everything I once new is gone and C# / .NET has made me weak!  LOL

Comment: Ok guys.  So to simplify my question.  It seems to me that there has to be a DLLImport definition and a way to call it that does not blow up inside the C++ DLL.  I may have some hell to deal with once I get that right in terms of mapping the pointers to something.  So let's say for this one what is wrong with how I am mapping it out:

    [DllImport("mfcs_c_64.dll", CallingConvention = 
               CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static unsafe extern byte mfcs_get_serial(uint handle, ref 
                                                     ushort serial);

Comment: My conjecture is that this is wrong:

[DllImport("mfcs_c_64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] public static unsafe extern byte mfcs_get_serial(uint handle, ref ushort serial);

That or what I am passing into it is wrong.

Comment: That declaration in that last comment is fine, apart from the needless unsafe. And it shout be out not ref but again that doesn't matter that much. So as you say, either the interop us wrong, or the params are wrong. So write a test bed dll to prove that the interop is correct.

Comment: Managed code is not making you weak. It is more like you are in a paradise where you finally can work without danger of screwing pointer arithmetic up anymore. No more buffer overflows (because we realised Arrays via naked Pointers). No more forgotten de-allocation (because the GC deals with that). Pointers and conditional gotos are at the same time: The most fundamental programming element. The most usefull programming element even developed. The most dangerous programming element ever realeased on Programmers.

Comment: I could not agree more.  Well spoken!  Here Here!